# What is the usable command to turn on GC for datanode in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When running `start-datanode.sh printgc` command to turn on GC, Apache IoTDB reported an error indicating that the parameter cannot be parsed. I checked the official user guide, and it states that this command can be successfully run. I also tried to update my using version from 1.1 to 1.3, but this problem still exists in both versions. I want to know what is the correct startup command I can use to turn on GC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run `start-datanode.sh -g` command instead of `start-datanode.sh printgc` command in Apache IoTDB version 1.3, and see if this can enable GC services.